# Setup >> file descriptor per redirection in a shell using C

Tags: c, bash, shell, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I am trying to identify '>>' redirection operators specified on the command line and perform the operation that a >> operator does in a normal shell (i.e. append the text into an existing file). The code provided below doesn't append new text into an existing file. It rather overwrites the contents of the existing file. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/* Setup >> file descriptor per redirection. */
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
if (ofn != NULL) {                /* ofn is output file name */
int fd = open(ofn,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND,0700);
unlink(ofn);

if (fd < 0) {
    write(2,CANNOTAPPEND,strlen(CANNOTAPPEND));
    exit(1);
}
close(1);
dup(fd);
close(fd);
}
execve(path,eveargs,environ);
write(2,CANNOTEXEC,strlen(CANNOTEXEC));
exit(1);
```

Comment: What does `unlink(ofn)` do?

Comment: You may want to read the manual page of [`unlink`(2)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man2/unlink.2.html).